# What's wrong with my using svn this way?

Tags: svn

I started svn server this way:

[user@vps303 trunkdb]# svnserve -d -r /repositories/
[user@vps303 trunkdb]# ls /repositories/
trunk

But when I connect to `svn://domain.name` it reports no such repository,

but when I connect to `svn://domain.name/trunk`, it's OK.

How can I connect to  `svn://domain.name` ?

Comment: What would you expect to come up when you connect to `svn://domain.name`?

Comment: A subdirectory of `/trunk`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to start your subversion server like this:

> svnserve -d -r /repositories/trunk

However, this only makes sense if you need just one repository and it could lead to confusion except your project's name is "trunk".